# How to create a scroll list of custom relative layouts not stacking upon each other in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I want to create a scroll view list which would show "boxes" or more accurately custom made layouts (I'm using a custom class that extends a RelativeLayout - basically shows different pieces of information, some are static like places' working hours and some change dynamically and will be pulled from a server).

Though I encountered a problem - I (for the sake of seeing if my solution works) created 5 boxes and added them to the scroll view list but it seems like they are stacked upon each other. What's the proper way to make them appear one under another without manually tweaking their position coordinates? I was using addView() for that purpose but it doesn't work as intended for me or I use it poorly. If you know the answer, please briefly describe how this should be done.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT, here goes the code:

```
public class RestaurantBox extends RelativeLayout {
    RestaurantBox (Context context){
        super(context);
        this.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        TextView restaurantName = new TextView(context);
        restaurantName.setText("Test Restaurant");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams restNameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        this.addView(restaurantName, restNameParams);
        restaurantName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        TextView freeSpots = new TextView(context);
        freeSpots.setText("15/20");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams freeSpotParams =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        freeSpotParams.topMargin = restNameParams.bottomMargin + 50;
        this.addView(freeSpots, freeSpotParams);
        TextView book = new TextView(this.getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bookParams =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        book.setText("Book");
        bookParams.setMargins(0,freeSpotParams.bottomMargin + 100,0,0);
        this.addView(book, bookParams);
    }
}


public class BrowseRestaurants extends AppCompatActivity {
    int restaurantCount;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_restaurants);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String login = intent.getStringExtra("LOGIN");
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWelcomeUser);
        text.setText("Welcome, " + login);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayoutRestaurants);
        RestaurantBox initRBox = new RestaurantBox(this);
        initRBox.setTop(0);
        initRBox.setBottom(300);
        relativeLayout.addView(initRBox);
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
            final View view = relativeLayout.getChildAt(i-1);
            RestaurantBox restaurantBox = new RestaurantBox(this);
            restaurantBox.setTop(view.getBottom() + 50);
            restaurantBox.setBottom(restaurantBox.getTop() + 300);
            relativeLayout.addView(restaurantBox);
        }
    }
}
<!-- activity_browse_restaurants.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.konrad.rezerwacje1.BrowseRestaurants">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewRestaurants"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWelcomeUser"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayoutRestaurants"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Logout"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWelcomeUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp" />
    </RelativeLayout
```

>

Comment: show ur xml and code where u adding view

Comment: @Pavan The code is added!

Comment: so views u adding in relLayoutRestaurants you want that to be verticaly stacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding view in **RelativeLayout** so view stacking on each other so change it to **LinearLayout** in **activity_browse_restaurants.xml**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewRestaurants"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWelcomeUser"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayoutRestaurants"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

now make changes according to in **BrowseRestaurants.class**

replace

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayoutRestaurants);
```

with

```
LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayoutRestaurants);
```

else will be fine if you want to change variable name its up to u, let me know if any problem